# plugin installation not working in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Am trying to install plugins from Jenkins web interface but it is throwing the below exception.

sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

plugins are not working with command line exeuctin also. below is the command

java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -auth ${USER}:${PASSWORD} -s ${JENKINSURL} install-plugin ${PLUGIN_NAME}

Comment: Which Java version do you use? Which Jenkins version do you use?

Comment: Jdk11, jenkins: 2.375.1

Answer (score 0):

You can change the 'update site protocol' from https to http . It is risky but it will fix your problem if you know you can trust that plugin source.

Go to your jenkinsurl/pluginManager/advanced

[image]

Comment: i have already updated this. but still it is not working